# Navigation link not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, accordion, sidebar

My website has a side column to jump to projects.
It uses multiple accordions.
The problem is that it sees the home and about button also as a page now.
and there is an accordion inside an accordion to divide projects by year.
For instance, 2015 looks like this:

```
<div class="accordion-head">
    <div class="title">2015</div> <!-- <div class="arrow down"></div> -->
</div>
<div class="accordion-body">
    <ul id="menu-toc" class="menu-toc">
        <li><a href="#item3">Rules for graphic designer from photographer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item4">Routine, But Antinomically Slipped</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item5">Visualization</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item6">Typographic fundamentals<br>An unconventional guide:<br>Table of Contents</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item7">Summer school</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item8">Dankjewel</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item9">Utopia is nearby dystopia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item10">Vertical,horizontal,halfcircle</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item11">What I believe</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the links are connected to the (item) tag 
This is what a page starts with:

```
<div class="bb-item" id="item3">
```

so it should jump to that page from the menu.

Any thoughts why it is not working?

here is the url to the website:
[jungeunlee.net](http://jungeunlee.net/)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to scroll to - is hidden!
This is your code :

```
<div class="bb-item" id="item4" style="display: none;">
```

Use JQuery to .show() first or make the element visible other way before you are scrolling to an element.

Elements that have display:none property don't get position x,y in DOM so they can not be scrolled to!

Comment: I think this is the problem!   could you explain me how to show it before scrolling to element?

Comment: J.Lee, I saw the page content, you have to change the logic of your menu vs the page, or use more sophisticate  js helper file to manage links in menu. The most logical solution is when clicking on <div class="title">2015</div> is to show the elements on the page related to that part of menu with .addClass of .show() JQuery, when hiding the index/landing page. This way it will scroll when clicking on related #href.

Comment: scarto, thank you for your answer. I am really not experienced with js and I've been struggling with this menu for quite some time. which line do I have to add to the page.js?

Comment: . menu-panel {overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;} to begin with, as to js code JQuery manual will help you. Another solution is in menu-toc to attach event ($('.some-item').click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); ... your code goes here ... something like $(some elements).show()})) as I see you have a book flipper inside, s you have to show all the book than it will flip to page you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your page.js file, there is a mismatch between the contents of your $items and $menuItems. The first two elements in $items are Homepage and About, these two have no corresponding element in $menuItems. The third element in $items is the one that matches the first element in $menuItems.

So, I guess that you could fix this by changing this:

```
            jump = function() {
                bb.jump( idx + 1 );
            };
```

to this:

```
            jump = function() {
                bb.jump( idx + 3 );
            };
```

**P.S.** I think that the href in the anchor links have no effect. The following:

```
<li><a href="#item3">Rules for graphic designer from photographer</a></li>
```

could be replaced with

```
<li><a href="#">Rules for graphic designer from photographer</a></li>
```

and it would still work.